# How do I prevent a stale element reference and make a WebElement update itself in selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, staleelementreferenceexception

I'm a complete newbie at dealing with python and selenium, just started a week ago, so do excuse my mess of a code. I'm trying to extract all the 'structure_id' and 'd' information from elements with tag name  in [this website](http://atlas.brain-map.org/atlas?atlas=265297126#atlas=265297126&plate=102339919&structure=10155&x=42476.80078125&y=16377.599609375&zoom=-7&resolution=124.49&z=2) and store each of them in a separate svg file. Here is a snippet of the code I'm having problems with:

```
for number in range(1,106):
    try:
        element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
            EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.ID, 'master_group'))
        )
        selected = driver.find_element_by_class_name('simstripImgSel')

        driver.get(driver.current_url)
        paths = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('path')
        
        for path in paths:
            while True:
                try:
                    structure = path.get_attribute('structure_id')
                    d = path.get_attribute('d')
                    break
                except Exception as e:
                    print(e)
                    paths = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('path')
                    continue
            if structure != None:
                print('Attributes copied.')
                for word, initial in data.items():
                    structure = structure.replace(word,initial)
                filepath = Path('C:\\Users\\justs\\Downloads\\Ordered_svgs\\slice'+str(number)+'\\'+str(structure)+'.svg')
                if filepath.is_file():
                    text = open('C:\\Users\\justs\\Downloads\\Ordered_svgs\\slice'+str(number)+'\\'+str(structure)+'.svg','r+')
                    rep = text.read()
                    rep = rep.replace('</svg>','<path id="')
                    text.close()
                    os.remove('C:\\Users\\justs\\Downloads\\Ordered_svgs\\slice'+str(number)+'\\'+str(structure)+'.svg')
                    time.sleep(0.2)
                    text = open('C:\\Users\\justs\\Downloads\\Ordered_svgs\\slice'+str(number)+'\\'+str(structure)+'.svg','w+')
                    text.write(rep+str(structure)+'" d="'+str(d)+'"></path></svg>')
                    text.close()
                    print('File '+str(structure)+' modified in slice '+str(number)+'!')
                else:
                    svg = open('C:\\Users\\justs\\Downloads\\Ordered_svgs\\slice'+str(number)+'\\'+str(structure)+'.svg','w+')
                    svg.write('<svg id="the_svg_wrapper" width="100%" height="100%" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path id="'+str(structure)+'" d="'+str(d)+'"></path></svg>')
                    svg.close()
                    print('File '+str(structure)+' made in slice '+str(number)+'!')

        selected.send_keys('F')
        paths = 0
        print()
        
    except Exception as e:
        print('Error.')
        print(e)
        break

print('Done!')
driver.quit()
```

This works fine for the first page, but I need to extract paths for all 106 pages, and after pressing 'F' once (which moves on to the next page) I get a stale element reference at the line `structure = path.get_attribute('structure_id')`. Initially I thought the paths took some time to load, hence the while loop, but by the second page it gets stuck with never-ending stale element references.

Explicit waits or refreshing the page didn't work too, I suspect the `driver.find_element_by_class_name` WebElement isn't updating at all (when I refreshed the page after moving on to the next page, the files I extracted ended up being the same as the first page, and I got a stale element reference by page 5 anyways). How do I solve this? Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You looped the url so it went to page 1.

```
driver.get('http://atlas.brain-map.org/atlas?atlas=265297126#atlas=265297126&plate=102339919&structure=10155&x=42480&y=16378&zoom=-7&resolution=124.49&z=2')
for i in range(1,106):
    try:
        paths=WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.TAG_NAME, "path")))   
        for path in paths:
            structure = path.get_attribute('structure_id')
            d = path.get_attribute('d')
        WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, "simstripImgSel"))).send_keys("F")
        time.sleep(0.5)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

Import

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: This worked! I also added `time.sleep(5)` before defining paths to make sure everything was loaded. Thank you!